# Will moldy washrooms attract rats to invade my basement?

Tags: pest-control, rodent

I'm concerned about a possible rat infestation in my basement, as I haven't been there since August 30th, 2023. The bathroom drywall is peeling from hot showers, there is mold in the shower, and I've noticed a small puddle on the upper left rim of the bathtub. Is there a chance of rodents invading my basement? It's important to take preventive measures, such as sealing entry points, removing food and water sources, and keeping the area well-ventilated and dry, to reduce the likelihood of a rodent infestation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mold in and of itself doesn’t attract rats. A sheltered area might.

If you’re concerned about an infestation, you should probably investigate and, based on your results, take action. That might involve a diy solution or professionals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a possibility of rodents. Seal entry points, eliminate food and water sources, and ensure proper ventilation to prevent infestation.